# Spring WebFlux return response when error occurs in Mono.zip but keep processing them

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-webflux, blocking

I have a REST service (let's call it 'MAIN SERVICE') that calls other remote services. For performance purpose I need MAIN SERVICE to instant answer when one of the remote calls throw an error ; but I need to keep listening to other calls response to log them or compute verifications.

Basically I have something like, a 'MAIN SERVICE':

```
public ResponseEntity<SomeType> mainService() {
 Mono<A> remoteCallA = getRemoteCallA();
 Mono<B> remoteCallB = getRemoteCallB();

 SomeType result = Mono.zip(remoteCallA , remoteCallB)
  .doOnSuccess(...)
  .map(...)
  .block();

 return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

An other service that calls remote A and do some things with result :

```
//TAKES 1 SECONDE TO RESPOND
public Mono<A> getRemoteCallA() {
 return client.get()
  ...
  .doOnSuccess(response ->
    //MANDATORY EXECUTION);
}
```

An other service that calls remote B that throw an error :

```
//ERROR TRHOWED IN 500 MS
public Mono<B> getRemoteCallB() {
 return client.get()
  ...
  .doOnError(exception ->
    //SOME LOGGGING
  );
}
```

My problem is that **call B** fails before call A and I want to instant return an HTTP response.
But then, when call A completes, **doOnSuccess** is not triggered (any doOnXXX method aswell).

I am not sure but I think the zip stream is canceled (saw it with log()) so A events are not triggered ?

zipDelayError is not a solution otherwise I have to wait 1 seconde before responding the error

Comment: Try to replace mandatory "doOnSuccess" with "doFinally"

Comment: Just to make sure, what you want is to keep handling the remote call to A while you already wrote response? Or do you expect to write result of B, flush, then write result of A afterwards (streaming results)?

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering

To amanin : doFinally doesn't work because when zip fails, the cancel signal is propagated to call A subscription (I enter in this step before receiving the response)

To Vincent : I confirm that I want to keep handling call A response even after already sending response to client

I know understand that zip propagates a cancel signal when one of the Monos fails but I want the subscription to these monos to continue. From the DOC there is no way to avoid a cancel signal from a zip; I thoutgh cache() could make the subscription independant but no

Comment: Best way I think would be to duplicate the subscriber, so that in the `doOnError` of each call you would write the error directly towards it and then recover to fail gracefully further on. You would then subscribe all this workflow to your own scheduler. That's the idea I can think about, I'll try to implement it for this is a very interesting and challenging case.

Comment: I seem to have found a way duplicating subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be working:

- cache both `Publisher` so that they are hot sources
- duplicate the subscription of the `zip` so that you can return one to client and handle errors in your local code
- handle error on the local code using `onErrorXXX`
- handle success on the local code using any transformation you wish
- handle error signal on response code

```java
  @Test
  void so_78147735() throws InterruptedException {

    var monoA = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> delay(1000L, false, "A")).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    var monoB = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> delay(500L, true, "B")).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

    var cachedA = monoA.cache();
    var cachedB = monoB.cache();

    var response = Mono.zip(cachedA, cachedB).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    var local = Mono.zip(cachedA.map(resultOfA -> resultOfA.replace("A", "SUCCESS")),
                         cachedB.onErrorReturn("FAIL"))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

    response.subscribe(objects -> System.out.println("response mono: " + objects.getT1() + " " + objects.getT2()));
    local.subscribe(objects -> System.out.println("local mono: " + objects.getT1() + " " + objects.getT2()));

    Thread.sleep(1000L);

  }

  private String delay(Long delay, Boolean error, String id) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    if (error) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(id);
    }

    System.out.println("delay method: " + id);

    return id;
  }
```

Comment: Hey Vincent thanks a lot for your answer it's interesting I will test it. I managed to find an other solution but it's probably not as good as yours? I will put my solution aswell